# Python - Does input keep a value if not stored in a variable?

Tags: python

So I am doing a roulette like loop, which works well, except it sometimes stop at the "# end condition" part (10 lines up from bottom), often after 2 loops. Is there something to know about input() keeping its value or something like that even without a var or am I doing something wrong ?

```
# -*-coding:utf-8 -*

import os, math, random

user_number = 50
cash = 0
balance = 0

go_on = True

while go_on:
    # to_find init
    to_find = random.randrange(50)
    # bet and cash init
    if cash == 0:
        temp = input("How many cash do you bet ?\n")
        if int(temp) > 0:
            cash = int(temp)
    else:
        continue
    temp = input("Which number do you bet on (0 to 49) ?\n")
    if int(temp) >= 0 and int(temp) <= 49:
        user_number = int(temp)
    else:
        continue
    # cash modif
    if user_number == to_find:
        balance += cash * 3
        cash *= 4
        print("Woot we got a winner\nYou're now at,", cash, "$ !\nThe number was", to_find, "\n")
    elif user_number % 2 == to_find % 2:
        balance += math.ceil(cash / 2)
        cash = cash + math.ceil(cash / 2)
        print("Yay you got some money\nYou're now at", cash, "$ !\nThe number was", to_find, "\n")
    else:
        balance -= cash
        cash = 0
        print("Sometime you win... And sometime, you're back to 0 !\nThe number was", to_find, "\n")
    # end condition
    print("Your current balance is at", balance, "\n")
    if input("Want to try again ? Hit enter ! \nElse enter a number\n") == "":
        pass
    else:
        go_on = False

print("See you soon !")
if balance < 0:
    print("     And better luck next time !")

os.system("pause")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an infinite loop: If you hit the bottom of the loop while `cash` is not 0, then on the next iteration, you'll hit the `else` part of your `cash == 0` condition whose `continue` takes you back to the beginning of the loop, which will then repeat forever.

Looking at what you are trying to do, my best guess would be that you have assumed that `continue` works like `pass` (which does nothing, and is equivalent to omitting the `else`-part entirely).

In order to figure out what is going on is situations like these, it might be a good investment to get familiar with a debugger, which would allow you to stop the code at any line and investigate the values of each of your local variables. There are plenty of those around, but an example of a good free one is [PyCharm Community](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/).

Comment: Thanks for you help, I'll check the differences between continue & pass and I'm downloading Pycharm

Comment: You're welcome. With PyCharm in particular, do expect a bit of a learning curve: It takes some time to get used to but once you start writing bigger systems, it becomes indispensable. YouTube has a couple of good tutorials on how to do debugging in PyCharm (just search for e.g. "PyCharm debugging") that you may want to take a look at if you get stumbled.

Comment: I'm currently on VSCode and it has a build in debugger for python which is easy to install, but I'll try and setup PyCharm before I need it. Thank you for the advices

Comment: The VS Code debugging experience is definitely also fine, and it's much more light-weight than something like PyCharm (although I find that VS Code takes a bit more fine-tuning to get started). In any case, let me try not turn this into a discussion on which IDE to use as that's a mine field of subjective opinions.

Comment: Indeed it wouldn't be the place for it. However I'm really happy to know VSCode debugger is enought to begin with (I often have to switch computer so the lighter the better)